# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning Elasticsearch not working in windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot seem to find anything related to my problem in stack overflow. I've downloaded jdk 13.0 and elasticsearch 7.4.0.

On cmd setting path to C:\Users\Desktop\download\elasticsearch-7.4.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.4.0\bin I execute:

```
elasticsearch.bat
```

Which outputs:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 9: C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.PathUtils.get(PathUtils.java:60)
        at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:69)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
```

I've read https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/43911 and people say they've solved it by increasing the ram in kubernetes. I have no knowledge of kubernetes and I'm not using it so I've decided to post this question.

Could someone tell me why running elasticserach.bat is failing?

**EDIT** : as developer suggested

I've read https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html and followed the procedure and still gives me same error message.

But my path seems pretty odd compared to the resource I've followed. This is my path:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\download\jdk-13.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-13.0.1
```

which gave me same error as before.

I've noticed java.exe is inside bin folder which is inside jdk-13.0.1 so I've tried setting value for system variable as

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\download\jdk-13.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-13.0.1\bin
```

and now it give me:

```
"could not find java in JAVA_HOME or bundled at C:\Users\myname\Desktop\download\elasticsearch-7.4.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.4.0\jdk"
```

I clearly see java.exe inside bin folder, why is it saying it cannot find it?

Comment: You can ignore the warning if you are setting up for development purpose and the github issue is related to that warning, issue is with exception, did you found anything with exception message?

Comment: If it is just a warning why isn't it giving port number so I can access elasticsearch? that is all message I've got.

Comment: The error is below one, but you were referring to warning in github issue which you can ignore, that’s all I am trying to say.


Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 9: C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME set to correct path?

Comment: I've only set Path from User variables therefore I can execute java on cmd.